# How to get the total intensity of a certain frequency range in an audio file?

Tags: sound, signal-processing

Does anyone know how to get the total intensity of a certain frequency range in an audio file?

Let's say an audio file has a frequency range from 0Hz to 20KHz, and I want to extract the total intensity of every 100Hz, then I can have the intensity of 0 to 100Hz, 100 to 200Hz....etc.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a minimal example? Is your question mainly about the signal processing part of it or _Mathematica_ part of it?

Comment: I am very new to mathematica, I try to get the data from the spectrogram but I haven't figured out how to do it and I can't find any references or examples of it.

Comment: An example will be to make an intensity versus frequency plot of a whole song. Need helps!!!

Comment: Have you imported the audio file into Mathematica?

Comment: yes, I get the spectrogram already.

Comment: Hi Joel, I tried the Fourier function and get a lot of data. But I don't know what the data means. Could you explain the relationship between the data and the value of frequency and time?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you read the documentation page on Fourier?  It's the discrete Fourier transform.  I sympathize with this, because while I took courses that covered Fourier analysis, I never took a course with discrete Fourier, so when I went to use this function, I was tearing my hair out to interpret it. I have a notebook I wrote for myself on the subject, but it's never been reviewed by someone who actually knows what they're doing.  This is a Q&A web site for Mathematica, so we need to stick to that.  We could take it up in a chat room, maybe others could join?

Comment: I think what I need is a FFT, but it seems mathematica doesn't has this function built-in. And mathematica takes ages to process a 3 mins wav file. I tried Matlab and got what I need.

Comment: But I still believe there should be a method to do FFT in mathematica. Joel, if you can do it, could you share some codes?

Comment: I think Mathematica's Fourier function is most likely the FFT. It would help a lot to edit your question to give things you've tried.

Comment: On my machine, the Fourier function took 3 seconds to process 3 minutes of 40,000 samples/second audio.  I don't call that "ages" -- something else must be going on with your setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer addresses some of your question, which is actually fairly broad and I think touches as much on the underlying concepts as on how to use Mathematica to achieve the stated goal.

This will answer:

1. How to import a wav file as samples
2. How to get the discrete Fourier transform normalized to give expected magnitudes
3. How to get a range of frequencies
4. How to get the magnitudes at those frequencies

Step 1: Import the wav file as samples:

```
signal = First@Import["D:\\audio\\Airwolf.wav", "Data"]
```

Here I use `First` to get just one stereo channel.  Use `"Elements"` instead of `"Data"` above to reveal other options to pass as the 2nd argument to `Import` to find (for example) how many channels there are and what the sampling rate is.

You can test your techniques by using a sampled sine, rather than a wav file, where you control the magnitude, frequency, and phase.  This generates 1 second of a 440Hz sine with magnitude 1 and zero phase shift:

```
Table[Sin[2 Pi t 440], {t, 0, 1, 1./10000}]
```

Step 2: Use the [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fourier.html) function to get the discrete Fourier transform:

```
dft=Fourier[signal, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]
```

I use `FourierParameters -> {-1,1}` to get magnitudes that you expect from the symbolic Fourier transform. For example, if signal was sampled from a 440Hz sine wave with magnitude k:
$$f(t) = k * sin(2 \pi 440 t)$$
then the symbolic Fourier transform will give a Dirac delta at +/-440Hz with magnitude k/2, and `FourierParameters->{-1,1}` will give the same magnitudes. Read the docs for more info.  The default option value normalizes the magnitudes differently.

You can plot the audible portion of this:

```
ListLinePlot[Part[dft, 1 ;; 20000], PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Step 3: Get a range of frequencies from 101 to 200 Hz:

```
range = Part[dft, 101;;200]
```

Step 4: Get their magnitudes with the `Abs` function:

```
mag = Abs[range]
```

You can plot the magnitudes for this range:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[101, 200], mag}], PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joel, I really appreciate your response. May I know the length of of your wav file in this example? Because what I am trying to do is to analyse the frequency distribution of a whole song, and the Fourier takes ages to do it. And I am also concerned with another problem that should I divide my audio file into several small pieces and do the Fourier of each and then sum them up? will it provides a more accurate result than to Fourier a whole song?

Comment: Did you read my most recent comments above under the question?  Fourier on a list of 7.2 million samples (180 seconds * 40,000 samples/second) runs in 3 seconds on my machine.  So if it is taking ages on your machine, something is wrong.  Be methodical. Take the Head, Length, and Dimensions of your signal and make sure they're what you expect (Dimensions should have only 1 thing in it, like {7200000}).